# Angular get current active component path

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have following routes and I am trying to get the path of the children component.

```js
const myRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: mainComponent
  }, {
    path: ':id/create',
    component: anothercomponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo : 'general-information', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'general-information', component: GeneralInfoComponent},
      { path: 'another-info', component: AnotherInfoComponent}
        ]
      }]
```

To get current path segment on reload i am doing something like this

```js
route.firstChild.url.subscribe(val => {
      let myRoute = val[0].path;
    });
```

Even though i am subscribing to url (in the anotherComponent) i am not getting the triggers if child route changes under :id/create i.e if it changes from 022/create/general-information to 022/create/another-info and to get every segment change for child routes i have to do something like

```js
router.events.subscribe(event:Event => {
    if(event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
    this.route.firstChild.url.subscribe(val => {
    let myroute = val[0].path;
    });
    }
    })
```

Is there any easier way to get the path only ? like just general-information or another-info ? If yes please provide the solution and if not what is the reason.
 Hope i explained it nicely but let me know if need more clarification. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

year later since no on answered you can get it like:

`this._activatedRoute.snapshot.routeConfig.path`

if you are on route let say `/dashboard/graphs` this will give you `graphs`